# How can I make sure that my private data is not in the future LLM training and there are no data leaks?

Tags: chatgpt, llm, openai, chatgpt-3.5, fine-tuning

I have question about data leaks and security in LLMs. Suppose I want to build a chatbot based on an LLM like GPT. I use the pre-trained GPT as a base model and I use in-context learning to ground the model for my private data. My questions is how can I make sure that model does not compromise my private data. GPT privacy terms mention they can use private data to train the model in future. How can I make sure that my private data is not in the future model training and there are no data leaks? Are there any methods which I can use to avoid potential data threats?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make sure that my private data is not in the future model training

You use OpenAI's API or ChatGPT Entreprise, whose ToS disallow OpenAI from using your data to train their models.

> in-context learning to ground the model for my private data.

Some attacks [may](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/best-practices-for-securing-llm-enabled-applications/) leak data used for in-context learning.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear exactly what you mean by your private data. But, I'm going to assume you have a corpus of data that you are training an LLM on that you don't want the exact text to be revealed by the LLM to the user. But that corpus is designed to educate the LLM in order to answer the questions appropriately.

If that is the case, I would use a local LLM to summarize and modify my data so that the concept is the same, but the actual text is different.  I would give it chunks of my private data and prompt it `"Please summarize this data in a way that the concepts and ideas do not change, but use as much different language as you can while keeping the same structure."` or something like that. That way, the model knows the concepts you're trying to teach it, but does not have the data.

The second thing you can do that's more expensive is have two models working together. The first model is trained on your private data, the second model is just a general model. You ask the first model the question, but return the answer from the second model. You give the second model the system prompts like `"You always summarize data and keep the ideas the same, but you like to use different language."` That way, even if the first model spits out your exact private data, the response of the second model will modify it.

Comment: This sounds like a nice idea if it is about private data not being shown in the answer. But I guess the questioner wants to get answers that are in-context. The questioner just wants to avoid a leak of the data, be it for data being stored in a cloud or being fetched by an attacker. Still your thoughs on this would be good if it was just about hiding the private data in the answer without losing the in-context answer. Still, that is clearly not what the question is about: "How can I make sure that my private data is not in the future model training and there are no data leaks?"

Comment: @questionto42 Check the edit history against when I answered the question. That was not the title at that time. In my opinion, the editor changed the meaning of the question.

Comment: I understand. And on the whole, it is not so easy to ask clear questions on data leaks if you it can mean a leak of the input or the output, and both are not so bad to think about. Your idea on this can still help some who hit this question in a diffuse search. I think it is helpful even for the edited question since it makes clear that you can also avoid leaks in the output. I keep that in mind for the future, never heard of it before. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you make the fine-tuning on top of the online models with a paid API key, you can be sure that the data is not passed to OpenAI, see [Do you store the data that is passed into the API?](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/do-you-store-the-data-that-is-passed-into-the-api):

> As of March 1st, 2023, we retain your API data for 30 days but no longer use your data sent via the API to improve our models. Learn more in our data usage policy. Some endpoints offer zero retention.

That does not mean that someone might not still fetch the data while it is passed to the model! Therefore, check offline models or anonymize all of your data so that a leak would not be harmful for your organization and its data protection. Yet, anonymizing all of the data can lead to mistakes and therefore, you might check the online model for a prototype, and once that it is good to go, check also the good offline models on your own machine, if it is worth the money.

---

If you set up a fine-tuning model on top of GPT-2 so that you can download the GPT-2 model to your disk and run everything on your servers or computer, you do not need to share anything with the GPT model online. There are newer and more powerful models as well, for example the German "DiscoResearch/DiscoLM_German_7b_v1" which is almost 15 GB but also (almost?) as good as ChatGPT.

Such a fine-tuning is set on top of the main model and will not leak to it, since it cannot, technically.

Check [Huggingface - Transformers - Fine-tune a pretrained model](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training#fine-tune-a-pretrained-model) as an example. The input data there is downloaded from a public domain, but that is not to have a public dataset that can leak, but just to have an example for everyone. If you were to add your own data there instead, it could not leak either.

If you say GPT-2 seems outdated, then mind that it is very small but still leads to good output, at least I read that from Towards Data Science 9/2020 [Fine-tune a non-English GPT-2 Model with Huggingface](https://towardsdatascience.com/fine-tune-a-non-english-gpt-2-model-with-huggingface-9acc2dc7635b):

> This is all magnificent, but you do not need 175 billion parameters to
> get good results in text-generation. [And it then goes on to praise
> this GPT-2 tutorial]

Even if you later need the best of the best LLM and go for a higher online version as the other answer would allow, you a GPT-2 prototype with nice output will easily afford a project with a higher GPT.